# Process a string into words seperated with the use of array

Tags: javascript

Hi so I have a question in Javascript, is it possible to use the given array such as

```
["old", "great", "other", "long", "good", "last"]
```

and if you have a

```
var str = "oldgreatotherlonggoodlastfirstnewownlittle"
```

and print it with spaces using the array and regex?

eg.

```
old great other long good lastfirstnewownlittle
```

I'm just doing a simple web app in javascript just for practices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) on the array to generate a regular expression, and then use this one with [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). In the next example I use the [replacement function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) of replace, it provides more control to the replacement logic in some cases. But you can avoid it and go with **@Barmar** answer.

```js
let arr = ["old", "great", "other", "long", "good", "last"];
var str = "oldgreatotherlonggoodlastfirstnewownlittle";

let re = new RegExp(arr.join("|"), "g");
let out = str.replace(re, (m) => m + " ");
console.log(out);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

However, note that the previous approach only works nice on some particular situations, but for example, won't work so nice for `var str = "oldotherlonglastfirstnewgoodownlittlegreat";`. Then, a more generic approach would be:

```js
let arr = ["old", "great", "other", "long", "good", "last"];
var str1 = "oldotherlonglastfirstnewgoodownlittlegreat";
var str2 = "oldgreatotherlonggoodlastfirstnewownlittle"

const separateMatches = (str, arr) =>
{
    let re = new RegExp(arr.join("|"), "g");
    let out = str.replace(re, (m) => ` ${m} `);
    return out.replace(/\s+/g, " ").trim();
}

console.log(separateMatches(str1, arr));
console.log(separateMatches(str2, arr));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: Thank you, you and Barmar's snippets made it very easy for me to understand!

Answer (score 2):

Turn the array into a regular expression, and add a space before each match.

```js
var str = "oldgreatotherlonggoodlastfirstnewownlittle";
var newstr = str.replace(/old|great|other|long|good|last/g, " $&");
console.log(newstr);
str = "greatotherlonggoodlastfirstnewownlittleold";
newstr = str.replace(/old|great|other|long|good|last/g, " $&");
console.log(newstr);
```

In the replacement string `$&` stands for whatever matched the regular expression.

Comment: Well what if the string was `greatotherlonggoodlastfirstnewownlittleold` and I wanted the code to print out like `great other long good lastfirstnewownlittle old`, then it'll require me to change regex over and over if the arrays were randomized.

Comment: The order of the words in the regular expression doesn't need to be the same as in the string. It matches them wherever they appear in the string. I've added that example.

Comment: Ahh was it just to remove the "var" in the beginning?

Comment: That's just because I'm using the same variable, so I don't need to declare it twice.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a way to make a regex from your array, you could do something like this:

```
let words = ["old", "great", "other", "long", "good", "last"];
let reg = new RegExp(words.join("|"), "g")
```

You can then use it with `string.replace` to achieve desirable effect

Comment: Note that you currently can't pass variable to regex using standard `/[a-z]/` like syntax. Here's the proposal for this feature: https://github.com/benjamingr/RegExp.escape

Comment: You can do `new RegExp("[a-z]", "g")`. That proposal is something different.

Comment: I meant that you can't do like: `let a = "str"; let reg = /${a}/` or something similar. I just didn't know how to describe it undersandably. (Still don't know to be honest)

Comment: The link you gave doesn't propose that. It's for `RegExp.escape()` function.

Comment: You're right :o I'm very sorry, I misunderstood this